# how to create a timestamp with only date in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

I'm trying to create a timestamp with only date.
this is what I get to work.

```
create table verses 
( 
     id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
     username VARCHAR(255), 
     content VARCHAR(1023), 
     time DATE
);

insert into verses (username, content, time) 
values ('test', 'blbabblabalbla', CURDATE());
```

this works but I need to insert the time each time. is there any way to do this automatically?
like similar to when we use TIMESTAMP?
I did try this but didnt work

```
create table verses 
( 
   id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
   username VARCHAR(255), 
   content VARCHAR(1023), 
   time CURDATE(TIMESTAMP)
);
```

Comment: So, can you use Timestamp type ? It seems you are saying that you tried using timestamp and it did not work .

Comment: if you want to use timestamp , try this : CREATE TABLE verses ( 
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
username VARCHAR(255), 
content VARCHAR(1023), 
`time` TIMESTAMP 
);

Comment: I don't want timestamp because I only want the date, not the time.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set your field to `datetime` instead of `date`.

Also documentation says:

> As of MySQL 5.6.5, TIMESTAMP and DATETIME columns can be automatically initializated and updated to the current date and time [...]

And also:

> For any TIMESTAMP or DATETIME column in a table, you can assign the current timestamp as the default value, the auto-update value, or both. An auto-initialized column is set to the current timestamp for inserted rows that specify no value for the column. [...]

If you want more information on this refer to the [official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html).

Comment: I see, I use MySQL 5.1.44, I tried your approach but didnt work, is there any way to get similar approach in MySQL 5.1.44 ?

Answer (score 1):

easiest way insert date(now()) instead of curdate()

Answer (score 0):

Try using DateTime instead of DATE type to store time also. As for inserting date with time, use NOW() function instead of DATE(). See [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_now.asp) for reference.

Comment: The OP is asking how to set a default value, not set the time. I think it was just a mis-worded question.

Comment: Thanks, kind of missed that :)

Comment: yes I'm looking for the default value, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you could set the DEFAULT value, like this:

```
create table verses ( id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    username VARCHAR(255), content VARCHAR(1023), time DATE DEFAULT CURDATE());
```

However, it appears this is not possible in mySQL:

> The DEFAULT clause specifies a default value for a column. With one
>   exception, the default value must be a constant; it cannot be a
>   function or an expression.

So, you either need to use a `TIMESTAMP` or manually maintain this, sorry. Technically, this is still manual, but you could emulate the automatic process using a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a BEFORE INSERT trigger and set 'CURDATE' for the `time` field always.